# How to add space after a text in textfield in ireport, when it's exported to PDF?

Tags: jasper-reports, whitespace, textfield

I'm using Jaspersoft iReport Designer 4.0.1. How can I add a space after a text in textfield? It trims the text when it exports to pdf. 
My textfield looks like this:

```
"Page " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER} + " of     "
```

But it's trimmed when exported to PDF. I don't want to change the alignment.

Comment: This strange you have another problem like font-extension there should be no need to add unicode

Comment: I have no idea! I'm using sanserif 10 and Helvetica for PDF

Comment: Search for jasper reports font-extensions, this is a very common problem to export correctly to pdf you need to add font-extensions.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the answer:

for each space \u00a0 should be added:

```
"Page\u00a0" + $V{PAGE_NUMBER} + "\u00a0of\u00a0"
```